# What does the term ふうん mean?

Tags: words

I was chatting on the internet and the term was used in response to a question that I had but the person was unable to explain the term to me. I am thinking that it may be an abbreviated form of ふうんいき。Thank you.

Comment: Probably this? http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%82%93 (By the way, 雰囲気 is ふんいき, not ふうんいき)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not. We don't reduce 雰囲気 to ふうん.

ふうん is a sort of filler meaning 'I see/ uh-huh/hmmm/really?/for real?/I don't care/how dare you/etc.

When it's actually spoken, the meaning of a ふうん or ふーん can vary very widely depending on the tones and context.
On the other hand, written ふうん/ふーん on the internet  generally means 'ic.'( I see.) unless it's not in a quotation.

I'm not enough adept at scripting an answer to show the subtle tones and nuances, let me look up for a video that explains well about variations of ふーん/ふうん。

I found a video that epitomises ふーん for meaning 'how dare you say such a thing!'.
It's hilarious actually that I want to share with you.

https://youtu.be/_9CUijejOT4

The male MC Mr. Shimoda reads a letter from a listener dubbed himself 'Koharungo2'.

The letter begins with 'Hello Mr. Shimoda and Ms. Tadokoro. I know this is sudden but I love boobs.'
Then Tadokoro who's known for her huge tits response with a consummate ふーん。
This is it.